Mapping Template to return unordered list of query parameters
I have a AWS Gateway API that is called, that looks like this...
https://[MYHOST]/status?TaskSid=xxx&ReservationSid=yyy&TaskCallSid=zzz
When I use lambda proxy integration, it rearranges the parameters in alphabetical order...
ReservationSid, TaskCallSid, TaskSid
But the query also has a signature to validate, so the order of the parameters cannot be rearranged.
I have tried writing my own Mapping Template, but it keeps putting the parameters in alphabetical order.
Is there a way to return the full untouched query string and pass it to the Lambda function?
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},

This results in
params: {
    path: {},
    querystring: {
      ReservationSid: 'yyy',
      TaskCallSid: 'zzz',
      TaskSid: 'xxx'
    }
}

Whereas I either would like...
params: {
    querystring: "TaskSid=xxx&ReservationSid=yyy&TaskCallSid=zzz"
}

Or
params: {
    path: {},
    querystring: {
      TaskSid: 'xxx'
      ReservationSid: 'yyy',
      TaskCallSid: 'zzz',
    }
}

